# Identifier expected.ts(1003) with Alpinejs and Astro

Tags: visual-studio-code, alpine.js, astrojs

I'm using Aplinejs (3.11.1) with Astro.build (2.0.13) and have the following on a div

```
x-on:click.outside="shownav = false"
```

I'm getting the following error in VS Code (1.74.3) on the "."

```
Identifier expected.ts(1003)
```

I'm new to VS Code, Alpine and Astro, so I'm not sure how to get rid of this error. Can someone advise? I'm using TypeScript 4.9.5.

---

Separate but related, for anyone getting the following error on "outside":

```
Property 'outside' does not exist on type 'HTMLAttributes'.ts(2322)
```

I sorted that by adding this to src/custom-attributes.d.ts

```
declare namespace astroHTML.JSX {
  interface HTMLAttributes {
  outside?: string;
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version of the Astro VS Code extension lower than `0.29.0` don't support Alpine correctly. (See [this issue](https://github.com/withastro/language-tools/issues/312))

At the time of writing, `0.29.0` is only available in Pre-release. You can update to it by pressing the `Switch to Pre-Release` button on the extension page.

[image: Screenshot of the extension page]